# how to use Image array on error or placeholder in glide

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-glide

i am trying to use image array and display image when image not load or any error occur.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

this is my code

```
int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.wallpaper_1, R.drawable.wallpaper_2,R.drawable.wallpaper_3,
            R.drawable.wallpaper_4,R.drawable.wallpaper_5,R.drawable.wallpaper_6};

 int img=myImageList[position%myImageList.length];
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(album.getUrl())
                .error(myImageList[img])
                .into(holder.image);
```

Comment: Why do you wanna send an array of images to error. If image loading fails, it just displays a single image url. There is no business logic in deciding the image for error case

Comment: in my api i am getting too much null image so i have to manage this by setting random image on error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in my api i am getting too much null image so i have to manage this by setting random image on error

This solution is based on your above comment:

Generate random number

```
 int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.wallpaper_1, R.drawable.wallpaper_2,R.drawable.wallpaper_3,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_4,R.drawable.wallpaper_5,R.drawable.wallpaper_6};

    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNumber = random.nextInt(myImageList.length);

    Glide.with(this)
            .load(album.getUrl())
            .apply(new RequestOptions()
                    .error(myImageList[randomNumber]))
            .into(holder.image);
```

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: have you tried your answer only drawable is allowed in error part not integer

Comment: I have tested the above code and its working fine on my device. Make sure you have the following dependencies `//Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'`

Comment: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to RequestBuilder<Drawable>
 getting this error on (myImageList[randomNumber]) this line

Comment: have you added above dependencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177484/discussion-between-prashant17-and-mitesh-makwana).